# QSqlQueryModel - How to add and delete rows?

Tags: qt

I am making my model which inherits from `QSqlQueryModel`

```
#include <QSqlQueryModel>

class SqlQueryModelBorrowingUsers : public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

//some class members

};
```

I also have a view that I set in `BorrowingUsersWindow` class and pass my model to that view.

in this view, i have two `QPushButtons` `add record` and `delete record`

```
class BorrowingUsersWindow : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

//some class members

private:

    SqlQueryModelBorrowingUsers *myModel; //my model
    
    QTableView *tblViewUserData; //my view

    QPushButton *bttAddRecord, *bttRemoveRecord; //I have a two buttons add and remove
};
```

Looking at the classes that `QSqlQueryModel` inherits from, I found

two functions in the `QAbstractItemModel` class

1. `insertRow(int row, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex())`
2. `removeRow(int row, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex())`

So the question is this. How can I implement adding and deleting rows with these two functions? Will someone give you a sample code?

Comment: This functions are used to update model and inform the connected views about the model update, and not for adding and deleting rows in database

Comment: @`Alexey` do you know how to add and delete records?

Comment: You can just use `QSqlQuery` to execute queries you need, e.g. `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. After query execution you need to refresh your model, that is re-execute it's `SELECT` query

Comment: `@Alexey` This is one more question - can you give an example of how to update a model using the two functions `QAbstractItemModel::insertRow` and `QAbstractItemModel::removeRow`? It would be good if you could give an example of use

Comment: You can not use this methods with QSqlQueryModel, because you do not control the model data, as it comes from database. This methods are used for custom model's where you have some kind of underlying data container and you manages it yourself

Comment: Check this example from official docs https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/sql/querymodel?h=6.3

Comment: And this one https://evileg.com/en/post/69/

Comment: `@Alexey` you are a nice friend. Thanks for these examples!